# Python: Installing virtual environment on network drive

Tags: python, virtualenv

I wrote a Python program that I use daily at work, and I was hoping to be able to pass it along to others who have zero programming experience.

I need to avoid having each user download Python and the relevant dependencies, and **I also can't compile it into an executable**.

I tried creating a virtualenv on a network drive, and made a .bat file that activates it and runs the script in the environment. It works for me, but other users get a **"Can't find python34.dll"** error when they try to run it.

Is there anyway around this? Am I going about this incorrectly? The goal is to have non-Python users be able to run the script without installing Python or compiling it all into a .exe.

Comment: Why can't you compile it to a `.exe`?

Comment: I mentioned twice that that's not an option, unfortunately :/ I was hoping to get around this by installing a version of Python on the network drive that others can access.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Virtual environments aren't relocatable, especially across different computers. `py2exe`, `PyInstaller` or `cx_Freeze` are your solutions.

Comment: I'm not trying to move it, I created it specifically in the U:\ network drive everyone has access to

Comment: Virtual environments are for local development, not for distribution.